# Peripheral does not communicate to Central

Tags: ios, swift2, core-bluetooth

I am trying to communicate through Bluetooth Low-Energy, our `CBCentralManager` implementation is already done in Objective-C, but I am trying to implement `CBPeripheral` through Swift.

I am not able to make the connection. This is how I am advertising in `CBPeripheral` implementation:

```
public func initialize() 
    {
        let queue =  dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
        perpheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: queue)
        startConnecting()
    }



public func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager)
     {
        switch peripheral.state
        {
        case CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOn:
            setUpServices()
            break
        default:break

        }
    }

private func setUpServices()
    {

        self.slideIndexCharacterestics = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: CBUUID(string: UUID.transferSlideIndex), properties: [CBCharacteristicProperties.Read,CBCharacteristicProperties.NotifyEncryptionRequired],
            value: nil, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.ReadEncryptionRequired)

        let services = CBMutableService(type: CBUUID(string: UUID.transferService), primary: true)
        services.characteristics = [self.slideIndexCharacterestics!]
        self.perpheralManager!.addService(services)
    }
 public func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAddService service: CBService, error: NSError?)

    {
        startConnecting()
    }


func startConnecting()
{
    let adData = [CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:CBUUID(string:"D6087B90-F460-4BE1-A9C8-E1CD8E7858E9")]
    self.perpheralManager!.stopAdvertising()
    self.perpheralManager!.startAdvertising(adData)
}
```

Note: I am able to communicate successfully if I implement in Objective-C both ends.

Comment: You need to show more code. How have you added the service and characteristics to your CBMutablePeripheral?  Have you stored references to these in properties?

Comment: added few more code.. please have a look

Comment: You need to wait until Bluetooth is in the powered on state before you try and advertise anything - don't call `startConnecting` until `setupServices` is complete.

Comment: did same... still not working..!

Comment: Also services should be a property, not a local variable